# Google Drive crashing Mac

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, google-apps

I am looking to uninstall Google Drive without fully loading the computer, such as through Single user mode.

I recently installed Drive and it is now crashing so my desktop will not load.

I tried loading safe mode, but I only get blue screen.

I am running Snow Leopard 10.6.8 and also have the disc to load from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Boot into Single User mode by booting with ⌘S
2. Mount the internal disk

   ```
   fsck -yf
   mount -uw /
   ```
3. Delete Google Drive

   ```
   rm -rf /Applications/Google\ Drive.app
   ```
4. Reboot

Comment: Thanks will try that now! Do i put /sbin/ before fsck and mount?

Comment: @user1791654 It should work either way

Comment: When in single user mode will I get some sort of confirmation that it is done correctly?

Comment: @user1791654 Not really, just wait for the prompt to return

Comment: It deleted, thank you! My computer still wont fully load properly, I think because of all the forced shutdowns. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user1791654 That'd probably be worth a separate question, with the output of a verbose boot (⌘V)

Comment: I actually got the desktop loaded just enough to see the Google Drive notification in the top bar asking for permission to sync with my computer. Is it possible it could be stored in a different directory on my computer?

Comment: @user1791654 It'll be wherever you saved it :-) By default, that's the /Applications folder, but you might need to change that path depending on where it actually is.

Comment: Ahh I see :) and do you know if there is any way to find where this is located without loading my computer?

Comment: @user1791654 You can try `/bin/find / -name "Google Drive.app"` from single user mode (don't forget to mount the internal disk), but it will take a very long time.